# Ignoring wrong wsdl=http://localhost:8080/service/wsdl

Tags: linux, java, tomcat, web-services

I've a warning in catalina.log

> com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser getPrimaryWSDL
>   Warning: Ignoring wrong wsdl=http://localhost:8080/service/wsdl. It should start with WEB-INF/wsdl. Going to generate and publish a new WSDL.

I just need to know from where it reads this information `wsdl=http://localhost:8080/service/wsdl`, I've checked the `web.xml` file and it doesn't contain this info.

I've checked on internet the method `getPrimaryWSDL` but I couldn't find where it reads this info:

```
if (wsdlFile != null) {
            if (!wsdlFile.startsWith(JAXWS_WSDL_DD_DIR)) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Ignoring wrong wsdl={0}. It should start with {1}. Going to generate and publish a new WSDL.", new Object[]{wsdlFile, JAXWS_WSDL_DD_DIR});
                return null;
            }
```

Any one can help to explain this?